# How to map/built the c++ vector from the eigen matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen, stdvector

```
MatrixXf A = MatrixXf::Random(3, 3);

MatrixXf B = A.row(1);

std::vector<float> vec;
```

I want to built the vector "vec" with elements from the row Eigen matrix "B". Something like this "vec=B.data()"

Comment: if `B.data()` returns a vector, then u can use `vector::insert`. If it returns one element at a time, then u can use `vector::push_back`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the obvious answer (manual `push_back`s or pre-allocation + index-by-index assignment), you can initialize it directly using the base pointer returned by `::data()`:

```
Eigen::MatrixXf A = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(3, 3);
Eigen::MatrixXf B = A.row(1);

std::vector<float> vec(B.data(), B.data() + B.size());
```

Just be careful that Eigen may use memory alignment to take advantage of SSE-family instructions, so it may not work correctly with higher dimensions.

Comment: A bit safer would be to store `B` as a `Eigen::RowVectorXf` (the initialization of `vec` can stay as it is then).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a loop:

```
MatrixXf A = MatrixXf::Random(3, 3);
MatrixXf B = A.row(1);
std::vector<float> vec(B.size());
for(size_t row=0; row < vec.size(); row++) {
    vec[row] = B[row];
}
```